# How do you override a command in bash but make it handle existing parameters?

Tags: bash

I want to override the `docker` command so that when I do `docker ps` or `docker service ls` **exactly** it will render in the format I want.

I started with this

```
docker() {
  if [ "$*" == 'ps' ]
  then
    command docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}"
  else
    eval "command docker $*"
    # eval "command docker $@"
    # command docker $*
    # command docker $@
    # command docker "$*"
  fi
}
```

However when I did it this does not work

```
docker service ls --format="table {{.Name}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Replicas}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

But

```
command docker service ls --format="table {{.Name}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Replicas}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

It appears to be because of the `"` characters being processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"$@"` rather than `$*` to ensure that arguments are re-quoted.

```
docker() {
  if [ "$*" = 'ps' ]
  then
    command docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}"
  else
    command docker "$@"
  fi
}
```